# Select a predefined maximum value

Tags: sql-server, select, max

I have a table where I have my users' data.

| Id | Name | VersionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name A | 1 |
| 2 | Name B | 2 |
| 3 | Name C | 1 |
| 4 | Name A | 2 |
| 5 | Name E | 1 |
| 6 | Name F | 3 |
| 7 | Name G | 2 |
| 8 | Name C | 4 |
| 9 | Name A | 5 |

There is a second table where I represent the versions where each of these users are:

| Id | Version |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 |
| 2 | 1.3 |
| 3 | 1.4 |
| 4 | 1.5 |
| 5 | 1.6 |

I'm having trouble writing a query to return users where their current version is 1.3. If the user has already had version 1.3 at some point, but currently it is no longer in it, this value should not be selected.
A user over time can transition through several versions. In the query, I only want users who are currently on version 1.3. That is, only users with Id: 2 and 7.

Comment: You can have many rows for one user in the second table?

Comment: Do you really want the maximum value or do you want the last value per user?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes A user over time can transition through several versions. In the query, I only want users who are currently on version 1.3. That is, only users with Id: 2 and 7. The user named "Name A" was at one point in version 1.3, but currently its version is 1.6 so it shouldn't be returned.

Comment: Are these strings or numerics?

Comment: Well it can't be integer but I suppose you mean decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MAX with partitioning.  Here I'm presuming that if a user is at a version higher than 1.3 then that user has already been at 1.3 so  WHERE clause can return only those users at 1.3.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #userdata;
CREATE TABLE dbo.#userdata(
  [Id] INT,
  [Name] VARCHAR(100),
  [VersionId] INT
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.#userdata ([Id],[Name],[VersionId])
SELECT 1, 'Name A', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Name B', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Name C', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Name A', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Name E', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Name F', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Name G', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Name C', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Name A', 5;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #versiondata;
CREATE TABLE dbo.#versiondata(
  [Id] INT,
  [Version] DECIMAL(18, 6)
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.#versiondata ([Id],[Version])
SELECT 1, 1.2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1.3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1.4 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1.5 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1.6;

WITH mx AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        u.Name,
        MAX(v.Version) OVER (PARTITION BY u.Name) Version
    FROM #userdata u
    INNER JOIN #versiondata v ON v.id = u.VersionId
)
SELECT mx.Name, mx.Version
FROM mx
WHERE mx.Version = 1.3;
```

Comment: I suspect that the userdata table is a history table and that the OP wants the last occurrence per user, i.e., the actual value.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I see what you're saying.  I still think this will work for what I'm interpreting from the question, just added the WHERE clause to limit to v1.3 (and the assumption I added into the answer).

Comment: @squillman Yes, it is a user versioning table. For new functionality I only want users who are currently on version 1.3. If they were 1.3 at some point it doesn't matter as I just want the ones that are currently.

Comment: @LSantos Ok, good.  Then this should provide what you're looking for.  This will return anyone who is currently at 1.3.

Comment: @squillman When executing the script, it returned (Name A, Name B, Name G). "B" and "G" OK, after all they are in version 1.3. But "A" is at version 1.6, "A" was 1.3 at one point, but currently it's not anymore.

Comment: @LSantos Ah, yeah.  Sorry about that, I see what I did.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry @squillman, did you update the answer? I tried to run it again and got the same result: Name A, Name B, Name G.

Comment: @LSantos Hmm, I thought I did but it clearly didn't update.  It should be updated now.

Comment: Great!  Sorry for the back and forth... ugh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function returning the last entry per user like this

```sql
SELECT
    x.Id, x.Name
FROM (SELECT
          Id,
          Name,
          VersionId,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id DESC) AS rowNum
      FROM UserData) x
      INNER JOIN VersionData v
          ON x.VersionId = v.Id
WHERE
    x.rowNum = 1 AND
    v.Version = '1.3'
```

This works even if a user downgrades to a previous version.

Returns

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Name B |
| 7 | Name G |

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93a572/15/0

Answer (score 0):

Start with a subquery to find the "latest" version for each user. In this case "latest" is defined as the row with the largest `id` value for each user.

```
                  SELECT MAX(Id) Id
                    FROM usertable 
                   GROUP BY Name
```

Then use the subquery to fetch the rows you need from your usertable, join to your versiontable, and use an appropriate WHERE clause.

```
SELECT versiontable.Version, usertable.Name
  FROM versiontable
  JOIN usertable on versiontable.Id = usertable.VersionId
  JOIN ( 
                     SELECT MAX(Id) Id
                       FROM usertable 
                      GROUP BY Name
       ) m ON usertable.Id = m.Id
 WHERE Version = '1.3'
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1d87bc/2).